# Windows batch file FOR /F Loop - how to get whole row when tokens and delims are used?

Tags: batch-file, replace, for-loop, row, conditional-statements

**Hello, dear colleagues...**

I have following problem. I need to change one value in text file pref.js (belongs to FireFox)

If this file conatins row:

```
user_pref("network.proxy.type", 1);
```

I should change it to:

```
user_pref("network.proxy.type", 0);
```

The only way that seems to work (in batch file) is to copy this file to a new one "line by line" and if I find the "network.proxy.type" row I do not copy it, but instead I write to the new file the desired row.

I do it like this:

```
cls
@echo off
set searchedString=user_pref("network.proxy.type"
set replaceSearchedWith=user_pref("network.proxy.type",0^^);

for /F "tokens=1,* delims=," %%j in (FileIn.txt) do (
  if %%j==%searchedString% ( 
    echo %replaceSearchedWith% >> FileOut.txt

  )
  if not %%j==%searchedString% ( 
    echo %%j,%%k >> FileOut.txt
  ) 
)
```

This works almost well. The only problem is, that the source file looks like this:

```
# Mozilla User Preferences

/* Do not edit this file.
 *
 * If you make changes to this file while the application is running,
 * the changes will be overwritten when the application exits.
 *
 * To make a manual change to preferences, you can visit the URL about:config
 * For more information, see http://www.mozilla.org/unix/customizing.html#prefs
 */

user_pref("accessibility.typeaheadfind.flashBar", 0);
user_pref("app.update.enabled", false);
...
```

As you can see, in the beginning of this file there are comments. And my algorithm adds comma (,) to the end of the last comment line. It then looks like this:

```
# Mozilla User Preferences, 
/* Do not edit this file., 
 *, 
 * If you make changes to this file while the application is running, 
 * the changes will be overwritten when the application exits., 
 *, 
 * To make a manual change to preferences, you can visit the URL about:config 
 * For more information, see http://www.mozilla.org/unix/customizing.html#prefs 
 */, 
user_pref("accessibility.typeaheadfind.flashBar", 0); 
user_pref("app.update.enabled", false); 
...
```

It is because my program joins tokens like this:

```
echo %%j,%%k >> FileOut.txt
```

**And now the final question**

Is there a way how to get the whole text line in my for loop, so that I would not have to join strings?

Or is there a better way to do my job?

I think I could skip first 12 lines, but I'm not sure that on each computer this comments will take exactly 12 rows. This script should be used on hundreds of computers in our network.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply check whether %%k is an empty string, before echoing the output:

```
...
  if not %%j==%searchedString% (
    if "%%k"=="" (
      echo %%j>> FileOut.txt
    ) else (
      echo %%j,%%k>> FileOut.txt
    )
  ) 
...
```

By the way, instead of comparing to `%searchedString%` twice you could only do it once by employing a single `if (...) else (...)` structure. Here:

```
@echo off
set searchedString=user_pref("network.proxy.type"
set replaceSearchedWith=user_pref("network.proxy.type",0^^);

for /F "tokens=1,* delims=," %%j in (FileIn.txt) do (
  if %%j==%searchedString% ( 
    echo %replaceSearchedWith% >> FileOut.txt
  ) else ( 
    if "%%k"=="" (
      echo %%j>> FileOut.txt
    ) else (
      echo %%j,%%k>> FileOut.txt
    )
  ) 
)
```

Comment: Thank you for opinion, but ELSE does not work in batch files I think. Or at least on my computer.

Comment: @Racky: There's one little catch about using ELSE in batch scripts which I wasn't aware of initially before I found the full explanation in the doc. In short, in multi-line IFs the ELSE keyword must be placed directly after the `)`, as in my code. The [doc](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/if.mspx?mfr=true) explains it as follows: `You must use the else clause on the same line as the command after the IF`. The closing paren is still considered to be a part of the 'command' (a group of commands actually) after the `IF`, so you put `ELSE` after it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not use `cmd` scripts for this. [Calculating π with only integer math](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Stupid-Coding-Tricks-A-Batch-of-Pi.aspx) is one thing, but trying to parse JavaScript code (even computer-generated) is road to madness (not to mention being really slow).

---

Second, mucking with user's `prefs.js` is not the Right Way.

You can set up distributed configuration in Mozilla software, as described in [Mission Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/MCD).

1. Create a `<programdir>\defaults\pref\all.js` with contents:

   ```
   pref("general.config.obscure_value", 0);
   pref("general.config.filename", "firefox-config.js");
   ```
2. Create a `<programdir>\firefox-config.js` with contents:

   ```
   lockPref("autoadmin.global_config_url", "https://configserver/firefox-config.js");
   ```
3. On *`configserver`*, create a `firefox-config.js` and make sure it is available on the aforementioned URL.

   ```
   pref("network.proxy.type", 0);
   ```

   If you want to *enforce* the proxy type, use `lockPref()` instead. (This can be overriden, though.)

You *could* skip step 3 and just use `network.proxy.type` in step 2, but would you rather update hundreds of config files *once* or *every time*?

Also, it would be easier to tell Firefox to use *system's* proxy settings (`network.proxy.type=5`), the same way IE and Chrome do.

---

If you want to stick to your methods, consider a different programming language. Perl, Python, JScript or C# are all better than `cmd`.

JScript and VBScript come with Windows. For C# and VB.NET, these days most Windows boxen have .NET Runtime installed.

Comment: I would suggest using a language like JS or VBS that is almost certainly almost already installed on the computer, rather than a language like Perl or Python which is not.

Answer (score 0):

@grawity seconded. Perl is portable. Why use anything else? Anyway, just to satisfy your masochistic tendencies:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%j in (FileIn.txt) do call :testformatch %%j& if errorlevel 1 (echo %%j >>FileOut.txt) else echo need something else >>FileOut.txt
goto :eof

:testformatch
echo %*| find "network.proxy.type" >nul
goto :eof
```

Ugh, makes my flesh crawl!

Comment: So you prefer to change his question from "How to do this in batch?" to "How do I get Perl installed without admin access on all the servers where this needs to run?"

Comment: @Gabe: Eh? Did you see/try the bat code Robin? It works as well as I suspect you could expect `cmd` (and `find`) to.

Comment: I was answering "Why use anything else?" -- the answer is that Perl isn't already installed. CMD is, as is CSCRIPT.

Comment: @Gabe: The poster *did* mention "hundreds of computers"; I would be surprised if they did not have Admin on the computers.